# i am getting an error when i try to replace nan values with zero

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pickle 

dataset = pd.read_csv('book1.csv')

dataset['Experience'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

dataset['Test_score'].fillna(dataset['Test_score'].mean(), inplace=True)

X = dataset.iloc[:, :3]


def convert_to_int(word):
    word_dict = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4, 'five':5, 'six':6, 'seven':7, 'eight':8,
                 'nine':9, 'ten':10, 'eleven':11, 'twelve':12, 'zero':0, 0:0}
    return word_dict[word]


X['Experience'] = X['Experience'].apply(lambda x : convert_to_int(x))

y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()


regressor.fit(X, y)
```

Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  dataset['Experience'].fillna(0, inplace=True) File "C:\Users\THUMMAGO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in getitem indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key) File "C:\Users\THUMMAGO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

Comment: dataset['Experience'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-a7cff2b3b8cb>", line 1, in <module>
    dataset['Experience'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

  File "C:\Users\THUMMAGO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\THUMMAGO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

Comment: please add the entire traceback as a part of the question details

Comment: What is the datatype of column Experience? Can you print dataset.dtypes after the line dataset = pd.read_csv('book1.csv')?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) For instance the data for "book1.csv" is not defined in your code, so its not reproducible.